# How to find the index in a pandas dataframe from xarray?

Tags: pandas, python-xarray

There is a multiindex pandas dataframe. It comes from a multidimensional array and is transformed as pandas df using xarray

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr    
rpsFile = xr.open_dataset("data/GIB.NC")
```

The results is as follows:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (ncells: 735, time: 26)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2019-02-27T16:30:00 2019-02-27T17:30:00 ...
  * ncells   (ncells) int32 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ...
    lon      (ncells) float32 -7.016703 -7.016703 -7.016703 -7.016703 ...
    lat      (ncells) float32 36.733208 36.75543 36.77765 36.79987 36.82209 ...
Data variables:
    FID      (time, ncells) int16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
    U        (time, ncells) float32 -0.151619 -0.16522583 -0.19049568 ...
    V        (time, ncells) float32 0.0758095 0.073865674 0.07192183 ...
```

Then I would like to obtain the ncells number from a position by lon/lat.
Using the ncells number I obtain the V and U values.

How can I get the ncells value from a position ?

Every cell number has diferent rows with diferent times (the second dimension and the second index of the dataframe.

[image]

Comment: Can you offer an example?